# change software configuration of a BLE device with a smartphone app

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth-low-energy

Would it be possible to change the software configuration of an [nRF51822](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-R-low-energy/nRF51822) over the air from an iOS application for instance ?

I'm interested in being able to change the UUID, the MINOR and MAJOR and the IDENTIFIER if it's possible (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile) on what the just mentioned terms mean).

Comment: Which UUID, what is MINOR, what is MAJOR, which IDENTIFIER do you mean? You need to restart the GATT server if you are changing service GUIDs. Yes, all of this is possible. I also have 4 51822 devices within arm's reach of me.

Comment: proximity UUID, but maybe reading [this](http://daveaddey.com/?p=1252) short article will tell you more about what I mean. It's more about the broadcasted data, I'm trying to build an beacon (iBeacon) and I'm thinking about ways to configure the device without having to connect it with my PC and deploy new code every time I need to update something or change something like what the article describes about the broadcasted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but if you mean changing the *software* configuration, that is entirely possible using a application specific profile.

Through my research into iBeacons, I came across [this helpful stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile):

In summary, you will need to create a writable characteristic on your device to act as a control point. You can hook code up to react to writes to that characteristic and change the device's configuration.

I don't know much about iBeacons, but if all you need is advertising, look @ this API in the SDK:

```
uint32_t ble_advdata_set(const ble_advdata_t * p_advdata, const ble_advdata_t * p_srdata)
```

By going through that and the question I linked to, I think you will be well on your way to developing your own i-device. (iBacon)

Comment: Yes, excuse my bad phrasing, I meant software configuration.

Comment: I've updated my question so it can be more readable and possible to understand